# Does the compact-open topology retain topological groups?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ a topological group. Then $C(X,Y)$ is a group, and can also be endowed with the compact-open topology.

Is $C(X,Y)$ in the compact-open topology necessarily a topological group? If not, is there some property of $X$ which will guarantee it?

Comment: When $X$ is compactly-generated and Hausdorff, then $C(X,-)$ is right adjoint to $-\times X$, so preserves limits (possibly you need to restrict to $Y$ Hausdorff as well). Any functor that preserves limits sends group objects to group objects. If you are happy with not quite the compact-open topology, then you can just ask that $X$ is _core-compact_. See discussion at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponential+law+for+spaces

Comment: check out section 2.6 in Narici, Beckenstein - Topological vector spaces